# How to work with Json Arrays when converting an xml to json using Python script

Tags: python, json, xml

I am having an issue where from an python script I am trying to convert an xml to Json.

But The Address array appears in json only if multiple address tags are passed from xml.

I am expecting this as below But I am not getting it in a array format and I want it in that format even if its one Record of addresses. Else the record is failing in third party application. with the error..

Has anybody work on this to create json Arrays from an xml using python script?

Error from third party application:

```
{

"code": "REQUEST_VALIDATION_ERROR",
"message": "Invalid schema for content type application/json. Errors: /addresses expected type: 
JSONArray, found: JSONObject. "
}
```

Expected Result:

```
"addresses": [
{
"id": "",
 "ifsAddressId": "",
 "addressType": "",
 "street": "",
 "postalCode": "",
 "city": "",
 "state": "",
"stateCode": "",
"country": "",
"countryCode": ""
}
],
```

This below is my python script

```
import json
import xmltodict
xml = xmltodict.parse(input_xml)
output_json = xml['BillToPartyMaster']
print(output_json)

This is the xml with address tags I am trying to convert to Json

<addresses>
<id></id>
<ifsAddressId></ifsAddressId>
<addressType></addressType>
<street></street>
<postalCode></postalCode>
<city></city>
<state></state>
<stateCode></stateCode>
<country></country>
<countryCode></countryCode>
</addresses>
```

This is the json output I am getting in Test window of python scripting

```
"addresses": {
"id": "",
"ifsAddressId": "",
"addressType": "",
"street": "",
"postalCode": "",
"city": "",
"state": "",
"stateCode": "",
"country": "",
"countryCode": ""
  },
```

Comment: Firstly, you use `xmltodict` library and the result you have defined by internal implementation of this particula library. What `xmltodict` docs say about option to output arrays\lists as result of parsing? Secondly, you get the `dict` by this library and somewhere in code perform actual serialization into JSON to pass further in third party API. This means you, probably, may additionally to `xmltodict` parsing make some transformation of desired entries of produced `dict` to replace one value with list of one element, like: `d['addresses'] = [d['addresses']]

Comment: Hi I am mainly struggling to keep array into array format. For e.g my address is an array but it converts to object if there is only one Address. I want it into array format even if one address